# Organizing Information in Columns without Tables

Tags: lists

I need to organize, without using tables, information such as:

```
Name: James 
Profession: Dentist
Nationality: American
Age: 32
```

I want entries in each field to look like if they were placed in a table, but without the table. How can I do that?

**[EDIT]**

I'm having trouble with this; I'm using the `tabbing` environment but when I compile the text overlaps with the formula:

```
\begin{tabbing}
\=Feature: \=Formula\kill
\>Elements: \>$ds = \sqrt{dx^{2} + dy^{2}}$, $ds^{2} = dx dy$ \\
\end{tabbing}
```

I don't see the mistake here.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `tabular` element?

Answer (score 3):

#### Update

Now that the question has been edited, the reason why the text overlapped with the code in the question is that the space reserved before the second tabbing corresponds to the width of "Feature: " which is shorter than "Elements: "; you can correct this in several ways; for example, using the widest strings to set the spacings appropriately:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
\=Feature: \=Formula\kill
\>Elements: \>$ds = \sqrt{dx^{2} + dy^{2}}$, $ds^{2} = dx dy$ \\
\end{tabbing}

\begin{tabbing}
\=Elements: \=$ds = \sqrt{dx^{2} + dy^{2}}$, $ds^{2} = dx dy$\kill
\>Elements: \>$ds = \sqrt{dx^{2} + dy^{2}}$, $ds^{2} = dx dy$ \\
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also (not related to the question), it's common to typeset the "d" in upright font, so you might prefer something like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}

\newcommand\rd{\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
\=Elements: \=$\rd s = \sqrt{\rd x^{2} + \rd y^{2}}$, $\rd s^{2} = \rd x\, \rd y$ \kill
\>Elements: \>$\rd s = \sqrt{\rd x^{2} + \rd y^{2}}$, $\rd s^{2} = \rd x\, \rd y$ \\
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### This is the initial answer before the edit to the question

I find the restriction a little peculiar. Anyway, you have several options.

Using a `tabbing` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
\=Nationality: \=American\kill
\>Name:\>James \\
\>Profession:\>Dentist \\
\>Nationality:\>American \\
\>Age:\>32
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

- `\=` set tab.
- `\>` move right to next tab
- `\kill` don't typeset line

Another option using the `enumitem` package and a modified `itemize` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlength\widest

\begin{document}

\settowidth\widest{Nationality: }
\noindent\begin{itemize}[labelwidth=\the\widest,align=left,leftmargin=!,noitemsep]
\item[Name:] James
\item[Profession:] Dentist
\item[Nationality:] American
\item[Age:] 32
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\widest
\newcommand\MBox[2]{%
  \makebox[\widest][l]{#1:}\ \ #2}
\settowidth\widest{Nationality}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{flushleft}
\MBox{Name}{James} \\
\MBox{Profession}{Dentist} \\
\MBox{Nationality}{American} \\
\MBox{Age}{32}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using a `tabular` (formally, this is not a `table`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
Name: & James \\
Profession: & Dentist \\
Nationality: & American \\
Age: & 32
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, now it works using `tabular`. Sorry I hadn't seen your edit before I edited my post. Anyway, if possible, I would still like to know the reason why `tabbing` doesn't work- Thanks.

Comment: @JamesDuncan please see my updated answer.